# Should the semicolon work with the Python global statement

Tags: python

I'm a bit confused about when semicolons work in Python and when they don't. 
In Python (3.4.3) the following code generates SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
global winSeqs ; if len(winSeqs) == 0: makeWinSeqs(boardSize)
```

The (3.4.3) language reference manual section 7 says:

```
> A simple statement is comprised within a single logical line. Several
> simple statements may occur on a single line separated by semicolons.
> The syntax for simple statements is:
> 
> simple_stmt ::=  expression_stmt
>                  | assert_stmt
>                  | assignment_stmt
...
>                  | global_stmt
>                  | nonlocal_stmt
```

I think this is probably a bug (perhaps in the documentation) but it'd be good to know for sure.

Comment: I don't think and `if` statement is a simple statement.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with the use of `global`.  As the documentation states, you can combine several **simple** statements with semi-colons.

A stanza of the form `if ...: ...` is not a [simple statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html).  It is a [compound statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#compound-statements). You will observe the same SyntaxError with the following code:

```
x = 1; if x == 1: print("wibble")
```

Comment: Great simple answer.

Comment: Arrh, makes sense. Thanks!